# How to imitate OneNote style sheet in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, styles

I was seeing that MS OneNote has a particular style like a sheetpaper. I wanna implement this background as my background's window, can you help me creating this pattern?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I was drawing just the red line and the first blue line. I haven't accomplished to follow the same pattern for the rest of the blue lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an image for one row of the notepad, set it to be the background and tile it using a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) or [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx).

**Update:**

If you tile an image like this vertically then the red line is drawn for you.

[image: Notebook background sample]

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="UniformToFill" Viewport="0,0,1,.2" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" ImageSource="ruled.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Comment: But how can I set the white space above of the notepad? And the red line, all together?